# Incremental learning - Set Initial Weights or values for Parameters from previous model for ML algorithm in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying for setting the initial weights or parameters for a machine learning (Classification) algorithm in Spark 2.x. Unfortunately, except for MultiLayerPerceptron algorithm, no other algorithm is providing a way to set the initial weights/parameter values.

I am trying to solve Incremental learning using spark. Here, I need to load old model re-train the old model with new data in the system. How can I do this?

How can I do this for other algorithms like:

- Decision Trees
- Random Forest
- SVM
- Logistic Regression

I need to experiment multiple algorithms and then need to choose the best performing one.

Comment: Which other Spark algorithms *do have* weights? I kindly suggest you *be specific*, and leave "any other algorithms" aside...

Comment: Question Edited

Comment: These algorithms don't have weights in the first place...

Comment: If I want to do Incremental learning, how can I do with these algorithms?

Comment: That's a completely different question (and a too-broad one, arguably)...

Comment: @desertnaut: Changed my question accordingly

Comment: Still too-broad...

Comment: Still, is there any chance in spark to do this?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at how they treat ML problems in a *streaming* framework - arguably it has to be close enough with what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this for other algorithms like:
>
> - Decision Trees
> - Random Forest

You cannot. Tree based algorithms are not well suited for incremental learning, as they look at the global properties of the data and have no "initial weights or values" that can be used to bootstrap the process.

> - Logistic Regression

You can use [`StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD) which exactly implements required process, including setting initial weights with `setInitialWeights`.

> - SVM

In theory it could be implemented similarly to streaming regression `StreamingLogisticRegressionWithSGD` or `StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD`, by extending [`StreamingLinearAlgorithm`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.StreamingLinearAlgorithm), but there is no such implementation built-in, ans since `org.apache.spark.mllib` is in a maintanance mode, there won't be.

Answer (score 0):

It's not based on spark, but there is a C++ incremental decision tree.
see [gaenari](https://github.com/greenfish77/gaenari).

Continuous chunking data can be inserted and updated, and rebuilds can be run if concept drift reduces accuracy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31253994)